# indexing clob column in oracle using solr 

Tags: solr

I am unable to index the clob clumn using my solr. I tried using clob transformer , but it doesn't work.

ANy idea on how to index a clob column in oracle using solr indexing?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, my clob column is transformed to something like this: oracle.sql.CLOB@6d21f653. I have made sure I have the right cases and I believe I have configured everything correctly. Then I tried to rename transformer="ClobTransformer" to transformer="ClobTransformer83943" (something invalid), I still don't see any errors on the command line, that means my transformer attribute is completely ignored. Have you found a solution for this yet???

Answer (score 2):

```
  <entity name="***" query="***" transformer="ClobTransformer" >
      <field column="CLOB_COLUMN" name="CLOB_COLUMN" clob="true" />
  </entity>
```

Works for me. Maybe you are mixing lower and uppercase? Debug and set a breakpoint in ClobTransformer.java

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is, that LOB is normaly raw binary data.
So transformation of LOB will only work, if you are sure, that the content of this LOB is something which can be parsed by solr, after translating the LOB.
Mostly CLOBs are used for text - maybe also in your case!?

I don't know, why clob transformer does not work for you. Maybe it's useful, if you explain, what "it doesn't work" mean - in your case. What have you tried before?
Walking trough the Internet, I found many issues relating to problems with the clob transformer.

Maybe it's an idea to let oracle transform the CLOB content before delivering the data to the DHI.
For example look at this, if the content of the CLOB is text: [ask-tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:367980988799)